# Spring Cloud Zuul + CAS5 causes 404

Tags: spring-security, session-state, cas, netflix-zuul

[image: requirement]
I have a requirement to run a Zuul gateway (Edge service) serving multiple OAuth2 and CAS secured applications. I have the applications working (Not shown) but have an issue with the third party App that is secured by CAS.

The Zull routes are set up like this

```
zuul:
  routes:
    authorization:
      path: /cas/**
      strip-prefix: false
      service-id: authentication
    external:
      path: /ext/**
      strip-prefix: true
      url: http://host2:9090/app
```

The problem

1. The user hits http://host1:8080/ext/xyz
2. The the user logs in successfully
3. The application finally returns a 404 as the url is now http://host2:9090/app instead of http://host2:9090/app/xyz

I have tracked this down to the third party App not being unable to find the saved request in it's requestCache due to it being saved using one session and retrieved in a different one.

Any help here would be very much appreciated as I have been looking at this for over a week.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was mssing something quite obvious. The returned URLs should not be http://host2:9090/xxx but should be referencing the gateway at http://host1:8080/xxx.

Once this was fixed everything has moved on.

Cheers